# Set array min forward and backward via recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion

Let's say I have an array **A = {a1, a2, ..., an}**

Suppose A is divided in blocks of size **b**

What I'm trying to do is:

Let **MinUntilHere** and **MinStartingHere** be 2 arrays of size **n**, where:

- MinUntilHere[i] = minimum from the beginning of i's block until i
- MinStartingHere[i] = minimum from i until the end of i's block

I want to fill this 2 arrays in a single transversal in the array... I was trying the following pseudocode:

```
int fill(int pos = 0){

    if(pos >= n) return INF

    if(pos is the start index of a block){ //i % b == 0
        MinUntilHere[pos] = A[pos]
        MinStartingHere[pos] = min(A[pos], fill(i + 1))
    }
    else{
        MinUntilHere[pos] = min(A[pos], A[pos - 1])
        MinStartingHere[pos] = min(A[pos], fill(i + 1))
        return MinStartingHere[pos]
    }
}
```

but as you can see, it's not complete, since it can't detect when each block is over and some returns are missing. How can I make a function that go through the array only once and compute my answers?

```
Example:
```

Let **A = {2,1,3,6,5,4}** and **b = 2**, the arrays must be filled like this:

```
MinUntilHere =    {2,1,3,3,5,4}

MinStartingHere = {1,1,3,6,4,4}
```

MinUntilHere[0] = 2 cause from the beginning of 0's block until index 0, the minimum is 2.

MinUntilHere[1] = 1 cause from the beginning of 1's block until index 1, the minimum is min(1,2) = 1

```
End of Example
```

Comment: Shouldn't MinStartingHere be {1,1,3,6,4,4}?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal sure, thanks for helping, fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following which does the job in 2 passes:

```
template <typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
void ComputeMinUntilHere(InputIt begin, InputIt end, OutputIt output)
{
    if (begin == end) {
        return;
    }
    auto min = *begin;
    while (begin != end) {
        min = std::min(min, *begin);
        *output = min;
        ++begin;
        ++output;
    }
}

struct MinByBlock
{
    std::vector<int> minUntilHere;
    std::vector<int> minStartingHere;
};

MinByBlock ComputeMinByBlock(const std::vector<int>&v, std::size_t blockSize)
{
    MinByBlock res;
    res.minUntilHere.resize(v.size());
    res.minStartingHere.resize(v.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i += blockSize) {
        const auto blockBegin = v.begin() + i;
        const auto blockEndIndex = std::min(i + blockSize, v.size());
        const auto blockEnd = v.begin() + blockEndIndex;

        ComputeMinUntilHere(blockBegin, blockEnd, res.minUntilHere.begin() + i);
        ComputeMinUntilHere(std::make_reverse_iterator(blockEnd),
                            std::make_reverse_iterator(blockBegin),
                            std::make_reverse_iterator(res.minStartingHere.begin() + blockEndIndex));
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/r34hkE)

You may notice than `minUntilHere` and `minUntilHere` are similar and just depends if you iterate from left to right or right to left.

`ComputeMinUntilHere` do the job for an entire range.

`ComputeMinByBlock` split the vector by independent blocks to fill result by block.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you cannot hope to fill the arrays in a single pass.

For example, if the block size is `N` (entire array), then to fill the entry `MinUntilHere[i]`, you need to have looked at all items before `i` and to fill the entry `MinStartingHere[i]` you need to have looked at all items after `i`.

Comment: this is the reason im using recursion. I can have a list L and do something like Min(pos) = if( pos >= |L| ) return INF; else return min(L[pos], Min(pos+1);

Comment: One pass by array is sufficient BTW, so a total of 2 passes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, but I was able to find a linear solution (running the array just once) with code much smaller. This is the solution:

```
int fill(int pos = 0){

    if(pos >= |A|) return INF;

    int mod = pos % b;

    if(mod == 0){
        MinUntilHere[pos] = A[pos];
        MinStartingHere[pos] = min(A[pos], fill(pos + 1));
        return fill(pos + bsize);
    }
    else if(mod == bsize - 1){
        MinUntilHere[pos] = min(MinUntilHere[pos-1], A[pos]);
        return MinStartingHere[pos] = A[pos];
    }
    else{
        MinUntilHere[pos] = min(MinUntilHere[pos-1], A[pos]);
        return MinStartingHere[pos] = min(A[pos], fill(pos + 1));
    }

}
```

It works like this:

- If I'm starting the block, set MinUntilHere as the A[pos] element, and make the MinStartingHere[pos] as the minimum of A[pos] and the return of fill(pos + a);
- If It's not start nor end of a block, just make MinUntilHere[pos] = min(A[pos], MinUntilHere[pos-1]) and for the MinStartingHere, set him as the minimum between A[pos] and fill(pos+1) and return him (to the previous recursion)
- If it's a block end, do the same for MinUntilHere, and for MinStartingHere, just set it as A[pos] and return it to the previous recursions.

An important detail is that when you start the block, you call a lot of recursions and then come back to the beginning of that block with the value for MinStartingHere, and AFTER that you call the method for pos + b, that means it will start to compute a new block after finishing the current one.

Thanks for the help anyway :)